# Not getting desired output for cin.getline(),

Tags: c++, file-io, time

I have just started c++ today and I have looked through many feeds on this topic. While searching I found a function called ignore which somewhat helped. My initial problem was an input being skipped when running. I found this was probably due to a \n still being in the buffer so I used the cin.ignore() function to flush it out. However, I am still not getting the output I desire. Here is my code:

{

```
    time_t current;

    char event[30];
    char details[256];

    char outFileName[21];
    cout<< "Enter name of file to hold the input.[20 Character Max]:  ";
    cin>>outFileName;

    ofstream outFile(outFileName);

    cout<< "Event: ";
    cin.getline(event, 30, '\n');
    cin.ignore();
    outFile<< event<< '\n';

    cout<< "Details: ";
    cin.getline(details, 256, '\n');
    cin.ignore();
    outFile<< details<< '\n';

    current = time(NULL);
    outFile<< ctime(&current);
```

}

For the output, the first line is black, the second line lists what should be on the first line and it is also missing the first letter, the third line is fine with the system time.

Comment: If you literally just started C++ today, that it's too early to post on Stack Overflow. There are thousands of duplicates of this problem here on SO, and you should spend a week or three just *reading* other posts...

Comment: It's not `getline` leaving a newline, it's `cin >>`. I highly recommend you start using `std::string`, though, and I would expect to be able to input a file name containing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Put a cin.ignore just after inputting the name of the file. The carriage return from `cin>>outFileName;` is being absorbed by the next cin.

Also I'm not sure if ignore is the right command to use here. If this doesn't work try `cin.clear()` or `cin.sync()`. Take this with a grain of salt, as I'm still learning C++.

Comment: I really appreciate the help. I'm going to try that right now.

Answer (score 0):

I am very confused.  Are you trying to read from a file, then write to a file??

EDIT: I think I figured out what you are trying to do.  You can ignore the below.

You are not reading anything from the file.  cin.getline gets input from the keyboard.  What you want is to instantiate a file object that reads AND writes to a file.

```
//Create a file that reads AND writes
std::fstream readAndWrite(outFile, std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
```

**Notice ostream, not ofstream (i.e. ifstream is for reading, ofstream is for writing, fstream is for both)**

```
//Check to see if the file opened
if(readAndWrite.is_open())
{
   cout<< "Event: ";
   readAndWrite.getline(event, 30, '\n');
   readAndWrite << event << '\n';

   //Same for the rest of your code

   //Close file
   readAndWrite.close();
}
else
    std::cout << "\nFile did not open! " << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine the following user input:

```
Enter name of file to hold the input.[20 Character Max]:  foo
Event: something
Details: blah blah
```

1. First of all, `cin>>outFileName` will extract characters from `cin` until whitespace is found. The first whitespace character after `foo` is the `\n`. This `\n` is *not* extracted so is still left in the input stream.
2. Then `cin.getline(event, 30, '\n');` will attempt to extract a line from `cin` with at most 29 characters and stopping when it reaches an `\n`. As we've just seen though, the `\n` after `foo` was left in the stream though, so it will only read up to that, which actually has no characters before it. Then the `\n` is extracted and discarded and `event` will be an empty string.
3. Then you do `cin.ignore();` which will ignore a single character. The next character in the stream after that `\n` is the `s` at the beginning of `something`. So that gets extracted and discarded.
4. Then you output `event`, which is the empty string, so you get a blank line.
5. Then `cin.getline(details, 256, '\n');` will extract up to 255 characters until it hits a `\n`, which in this case will extract `omething` (remember, we alread ignored the `s`) and then extract and discard the following `\n`.
6. Then `cin.ignore()` will ignore the first character of `blah blah`, which is the `b`.
7. Then you output `details` which contains `omething`.
8. Then you output the system time, which as you say, is fine, since it's not coming from the input stream.

So the main problem is that you're using `cin.ignore()` in the wrong place. You're using it after `getline`, but `getline` *does* extract and discard the `\n` at the end of the line. The place you need to use `cin.ignore()` is when you use `>>` to extract from `cin`. This *doesn't* extract the new line, it just stops at it.

Simply get rid of the `cin.ignore()`s you have at the moment, and place one after `cin>>outFileName;`.

However, consider the issue when the user enters `foo bar` as the file name. The `foo` will be extracted, but `bar\n` will be left in the stream. If you want to ignore the rest of the line, you need to do:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```